# std::hex/std::oct not working (printing decimal value)

Tags: c++

when i try to print a number  in `Hex` or `oct` format i get decimal output instead of converted values

I don't think class definitions are necessary but here's `Number`

```
class Number
{
public:
    Number(double);

    virtual void show () =0;

protected:
    double number;
};
```

And for instance HexN.h (still i feel like problem's not caused by these)

```
#include "Number.h"
#pragma once

class Hex : public Number
{
public:
    Hex(double);

    virtual void show ();
};
```

The `show()` function. it's not working and simply prints back decimal rather than desired base

```
void Hex::show()
{
    //std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield); //Once i commented //std::hex 
    cout <<"Hex value is : "<<std::hex<<number<<endl;
}
```

Searched stackoverflow and other websites but all of 'em said use `std::cout<<std::hex<<number;` And this function is magically not working here.

EDIT: Thanks guys , problem solved by changing `std::hex` to `std::floathex` And casting `double` to `long int` for octal base.

Comment: How do you expect doubles to be represented in hex?

Comment: Off-topic but I think it's important that `#pragma once` shall precede the `#include`-s.

Comment: Instead of editing the question you can post an answer. It's allowed, and even encouraged.

Answer (score 7):

`std::hex` [modifies the default numeric base for integer I/O](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) , not for floating point I/O.

Use [`std::hexfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) instead.